# Very basic question on group representation theory

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations

I'm sorry for this naive question. I feel that since I was first introduced to the idea of group representation, I did not correctly grasp the idea. Unfortunately, therefore, several confusions keep bothering me. The definition of representation that I know (from Maggiore's QFT book, and Howard Georgi's Lie Algebras in Particle Physics) is highlighted below.

> A representation of a group $\mathcal{G}$ on a vector space $\mathbb{V}$ is a *mapping* $\mathcal{D}: g\rightarrow \mathcal{D}(g)$ (sometimes also written as $\mathcal{D}: \mathcal{G}\to GL(\mathbb{V})$) onto a set of *invertible linear* operators $GL(\mathbb{V})$ such that $$\mathcal{D}(e)=\mathbb{1}\tag{1}$$ where $\mathbb{1}$ is the identity operator in the space $GL(\mathbb{V})$. For any two elements $g_1,g_2\in\mathcal{G}$,$$\mathcal{D}(g_1)\mathcal{D}(g_2)=\mathcal{D}(g_1*g_2).\tag{2}$$

Now I have a few questions regarding this.

**Question 1** The definition of representation that I stated above (i) doesn't require the associativity $$\Big(\mathcal{D}(g_1)\mathcal{D}(g_2)\Big)\mathcal{D}(g_3)=\mathcal{D}(g_1)\Big(\mathcal{D}(g_2)\mathcal{D}(g_3)\Big)$$ has to be satisfied, and (ii) doesn't require that $$\mathcal{D}(g^{-1})=\mathcal{D}^{-1}(g)$$ have to be satisfied. *Does it mean that $GL(\mathbb{V})$ does not form a group? That cannot be true. In that case, what am I missing?*

**Question 2** For concreteness, suppose I want to understand the representation of the group $\mathcal{G}={\rm SO(3)}$. What is $\mathbb{V}$ in this case? And what is $GL(\mathbb{V})$ in this case? To be even more concrete, if $\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{R}^3$, $GL(\mathbb{V})$ has to be to a set of $3\times 3$ matrices. Should these representation matrices need to be *orthogonal* and *unimodular*? Does it follow from the definition of representation? Let us consider a different representation. Say a 5-dimensional representation of SO(3). What is $\mathbb{V}$ and $GL(\mathbb{V})$ in this case? Should these representation matrices again need to be *orthogonal* and *unimodular*?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: At to you last Question for v2: $\mathbb{V}$ can be as you say but there is - for instance - an irrep of SO3 of dimension $5$: the states of angular momentum $L=2$ are a basis for this.  The SO3 matrices would then be orthogonal and unimodular.  Note that in many cases we can do a little more by using the complex form $e^{i\theta}$ rather than the real $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$, and complex rather than strictly real basis vectors.  For SO3 representations (integer angular momentum) the ${\cal D}$ matrices are just those from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are wrong about associativity and compatibility of inverses not being implied by eq. (1) and (2). We have:
   \begin{align} \left(D(g_1)D(g_2)\right)D(g_3) & \overset{(1)}{=} D(g_1g_2)D(g_3) \overset{(1)}{=} D\left( (g_1g_2)g_3\right) = D\left( g_1 (g_2 g_3) \right) \overset{(1)}{=} D(g_1) D(g_2g_3) \\ & \overset{(1)}{=} D(g_1)\left( D(g_2) D(g_3)\right),\end{align}
   where the only equality that does not hold because of eq. (1) is just associativity in the original group. Likewise, eq. (2) implies that $D(g^{-1}) = D(g)^{-1}$, try to figure that one out yourself.
2. There is no "the" representation of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, there are countably many different ones up to isomorphism, which we physicists usually label by their half-integral spin $s\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$. For each of these representations, the representation space is $\mathbb{V} = \mathbb{C}^{2s + 1}$. I don't understand what you mean by "What is $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{V})$?" - this is *always* the group of invertible matrices on $\mathbb{V}$, i.e. all matrices with non-zero determinant, and the image of $G$ under the representation map $D$ is some subgroup of it. (It is a subgroup precisely because of point 1.)

   Since you seem to actually want to ask whether e.g. a three-dimensional representation of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ always has $D(\mathrm{SO}(3)$ as being unimodular orthogonal matrices, the answer is no. For instance, you could very well choose the trivial representation
   $$ D: \mathrm{SO}(3) \to \mathrm{GL}(3), A\mapsto \mathbf{1}_3,$$
   where $\mathbf{1}_3$ is the three-dimensional identity.

   If you require the representation to be three-dimensional and [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation), then $D(\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is always *isomorphic* as a group to the group of unimodular orthogonal matrices, but it need not be *equal* to that group as a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(3)$. For instance, any [conjugate subgroup](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate_subgroups) to the subgroup of unimodular orthogonal matrices would also be an irreducible representation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think what the OP might be getting as is: are *all* representations of SO3 by orthogonal unimodular matrices or just the defining $3\times 3$ rep.

Comment: @SRS I already said that $D(\mathrm{SO}(3))$ is only a *subgroup* of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$, since $D$ was never required to be surjective. What the image of $G$ under the representation map - the matrices $G$ is represented by - looks like is a completely different question from what $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is.

Comment: _I already said that D(SO(3)) is only a subgroup of GL(V)_. Okay. I think I was confusing between D(SO(3)) and GL(V); I was equating the two. My question is about D(SO(3)). Does it have to be orthogonal and unimodular for vector, tensor etc representations? @ACuriousMind

Comment: @ACuriousMind Probably it's better to ask _why is the subgroup D, of any dimension, have to be unimodular and orthogonal._

Comment: @SRS Alright, I edited the answer.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. But by GL$(3)$ do you mean GL$(\mathbb{R}^3)$? In the bracket GL$(\mathbb{V})$, the vector space $\mathbb{V}$ supposed to be specified. I suspect this because physicists often call the 3-dimensional irreducible representation to be the vector representation (they loosely refer the vector space $\mathbb{V}$ itself).  Similarly, the 5-dimensional irreducible representation is called the traceless symmetric tensor representation in which case your notation generalizes to GL$(5)$. Does that mean you refer to GL$(\mathbb{R}^5)$? @ACuriousMind

Comment: @SRS I wrote it that way because I want to be agnostic about whether we're dealing with real or complex vector spaces. That is, you can either substitute $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ or $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{C}^3)$ there, it does not matter.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Even when we have GL$(\mathbb{C}^3)$, does the three-dimensional irreducible representation D(SO(3)) continue to be isomorphic to group of unimodular, orthogonal matrices? But why? The reason for orthogonality and unimodularity when $\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively was that length of vectors had to be preserved and handedness of the coordinate system had to be preserved. But I don't see any such constraint to be satisfied when you take $\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{C}^3$.

Comment: @SRS The question makes sense to me, but the rest of your comment does not. The reason the images of all irreducible 3d representations are isomorphic lies in doing proper representation theory (and these comments or this answer is not the place to teach you that), not in anything about "lengths of vectors".

Comment: But you did not write whether the irreps of SO(3) of any dimension have to be unimodular, orthogonal matrices?

Comment: @SRS I did: *"For instance, any conjugate subgroup to the subgroup of unimodular orthogonal matrices would also be an irreducible representation."* Since already in the 3d case the matrices need not be unimodular orthogonal, it makes no sense to ask whether they have to be that in other dimensions.

Comment: I asked about irreps. You yourself asserted in your answer that three-dimensional irreps are isomorphic to the group of $3\times 3$ unimodular, orthogonal matrices. @ACuriousMind

Comment: @SRS By pure dimension counting ($\mathrm{SO}(3)$ has dimension 3, but $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ (which is isomorphic to unimodular, orthogonal n-by-n matrices) has dimension $n(n-1)/2$), the image of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ in higher-dimensional representations cannot be the group of unimodular orthogonal matrices in these dimensions.

Comment: @ACuriousMind _"Since already in the 3d case the matrices need not be unimodular orthogonal, it makes no sense to ask whether they have to be that in other dimensions._ I still don't get this point of yours. (1) In the 3D case (i.e., when the vector space has dimension 3) all the representation matrices must also be $3\times 3$, by the very definition of the dimension of a representation.  (2) Moreover, if they are irreps they must be also orthogonal and unimodular.  So how on earth can they be anything different from being isomorphic to SO(3) if I combine statements (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 1):

Associativity of composition is a general property of maps between sets, it is independent of any group representation. ${D(g)}^{-1}=D(g^{-1})$ is a simple consequence of your properties (1), (2).